# Using jQuery-chosen on a form select populated through javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

**I am trying to integrate jquery-chosen [jquery-chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) into my application.**

I have **two select controls**: when a user selects an option from the first one, the **second one updates dynamically** (through jQuery) according to the value selected from the first one (classic cascading selects).

It is in the second select control that I wish to use jquery-chosen.

**Here is my js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var geolocationRegionSelect = $("#geolocationRegionSelect");//first select control
    geolocationRegionSelect.bind('change', function(event) {
        $.get("/kadjoukor/geolocations/findDepartmentsByRegion?regionId="+$(this).val(), function(result){
            console.log(result);        
            var geolocationDepartmentSelect = $("#geolocationDepartmentSelect");//second select control
            geolocationDepartmentSelect.empty();
            $.each(result, function() {
                geolocationDepartmentSelect.append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.department));
            });
        }, 'json');
        $("#geolocationDepartmentSelect").trigger("liszt:updated");
    });
});
```

**Here is the html for the second control**:

```
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="geolocationDepartmentSelect"  data-placeholder="Choose a department" multiple="multiple" class="chzn-select chzn-done"></select>
    </div>
```

**I noticed that using jquery-chosen on a statically populated select works fine**. It is only with my dynamically populated select (the second one) that I can't get jquery-chosen to work.

I tried to use the trigger function as documented in the jq-chosen page:

> **Updating Chosen Dynamically**
>
> If you need to update the options in your
> select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to
> trigger the "liszt:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build
> itself based on the updated content.

It does not work for me unfortunately...

**EDIT:** I must also mention that the chosen control just renders as a plain html multiple select when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the select control to:

```
<select id="geolocationDepartmentSelect"  data-placeholder="Choose a department" multiple="multiple" class="chzn-select"></select>
```

and the js to:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
```

and

```
$(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

and the issue is gone.